# returning a functional component directly from within a component's event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

I am relatively new to React.

I have a React menu component in which I have tried to use React Router from a sidenav. There are two hyperlinks in the sidenav, which, when clicked, should redirect to another component. Normal React Routing, though, is not working.

As an alternative, I have implemented a separate functional component Redir() that is calling history.push() explicitly in order to navigate to the other component (history.push() cannot be called directly from within the component.)

Im HomelinkClicked(), for example, I make use of the return statement in order to return an instance of the functional component Redir but I doubt that this is working. In fact, the alert inside Redir() is never reached.

Is it possible anyway to use a return statement for returning a functional component directly from within a component's event handler? Also, I am not sure whether it is safe to use a functional component to return other than JSX.

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    class MyMenu extends Component {
      constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
          };
        this.HomelinkClicked = this.HomelinkClicked.bind(this);
        this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked = this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked.bind(this);
      }

      HomelinkClicked() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
        return <Redir target="/AppjQM" />;
      }

      AppjQMPage2linkClicked() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
        return <Redir target="/AppjQMPage2" />;
      }

      render() {
          return (
            <div id="mySidenav"  class="sidenav">
              <a href="#" class="closebtn" onClick={this.CloseClicked}>&times;</a>
                <Router>
                  <Link onClick={this.HomelinkClicked} >Home</Link>
                  <Link onClick={this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked} >AppjQMPage2</Link>
                </Router>
            </div>
          );
      }
     }

    function Redir(props) {

      alert('Hook!');
      let history = useHistory();
      history.push(props.target);
    }
```

Comment: I think `<Link>` does not work this way. You should specify the path you want to go to in its `to` attribute.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` in react is an anti pattern. Instead, you should update state so that the next render makes the appropriate changes to the appearance of the components.

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:**  In your **App.js** file, you need to define the routes like the example below

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

     function App(){
        return <div>
             <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/AppjQMPage2" component={MyComponent} />
               <Route exact path="/path2" component={MyOtherComponent} />
               <Route exact path="/path3" component={SomeOtherComponent} />
             </Switch>
           </div>
        }
```

**Step2:**  Now you will use Link in your component like the example below and **not use** onClick handler in it.

```
    render() {
          return (
            <div id="mySidenav"  class="sidenav">
              <a href="#" class="closebtn" onClick={this.CloseClicked}>&times;</a>
           
                  <Link to="/AppjQMPage2"> AppjQMPage2 </Link>
                  <Link to="/path1"> balh </Link>
                  <Link to="/path2"> balhBlah </Link>
            </div>
          );
      }
```

For routing on **button click**, you can do so anywhere **provided the routes are defined** as given above in App.js

Example below,

```
import React from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleOnClick = () => history.push('/AppjQMPage2');

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Instead of the handleOnClick from the above example, you shall use your function

```
        AppjQMPage2linkClicked() {

            // Avoid using these document objects, use state instead or... for DOM access research on React Refs
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
            
            let history = useHistory();
            history.push("/AppjQMPage2"); // routing happens here
          }
```

Example for the **Redirect**,

```
 import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

    handleOnClick = () => {
         this.setState({redirect: true});
       }

   render() {
      if (this.state.redirect) {
         return <Redirect push to="/path1" />;
        }

     return <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Button</button>;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you also have to bind Redir function, like you did with other two functions HomelinkClicked and AppjQMPage2linkClicked

```
this.Redir  = this.Redir.bind(this);
```

OR you can use ES6 arrow function and  it can directly bind the Redir function to the class component MyMenu.

```
Redir = (props) => {
      alert('Hook!');
      let history = useHistory();
      history.push(props.target);
    }
```

And you should to use Route instead of Link.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. Routing isn't going to work, I tried that but discovered that there was some infinite loop going with MyMenu nested in AppjQM/AppjQMPage2 when clicking the routing links, freezing the UI completely.

So decided to rewrite the App entirely, have a top-level App with MyMenu rendering only once, followed by either AppjQM or AppjQMPage2 depending om the value of a state variable called activecomponent, that can be toggled from outside the component, from MyMenu, by clicking hyperlinks with a simple onClick handler.

This isn't working until now. The first hyperlink (Home) works without problems, but the second one (AppjQMPage2) is not showing any of the contents of AppjQMPage2. It only says: Hello from AppjQMPage2 and doesn't show any header or whatever is told AppjQMPage2 to render:

```
<JQMHeader />
<JQMPanel />
```

Here is the complete code and css/html for who wants to reproduce:

```
// client/src/App.js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './hamburger.css';
import './style.css';
import $ from "jquery"; 
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activecomponent: 1
    };
  }

  changeState1 = () =>{
    this.setState({ activecomponent: 1 }, function () {
      //alert('State is now: ' + this.state.activecomponent);
    });  
  }

  changeState2 = () =>{
    this.setState({ activecomponent: 2 }, function () {
      //alert('State is now: ' + this.state.activecomponent);
    });  
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.activecomponent === 1) {
      return (
        <div>
          <MyMenu parentCallback1={this.changeState1} parentCallback2={this.changeState2} />
          <AppjQM />
          <div>Hello from AppjQM</div>
        </div>
      );     
    }
    if (this.state.activecomponent === 2) {
      return (
        <div>
          <MyMenu parentCallback1={this.changeState1} parentCallback2={this.changeState2} />
          <AppjQMPage2 />
          <div>Hello from AppjQMPage2</div>
        </div>
      );     
    }
  }
}

class AppjQM extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div data-role="page" id="afsprakenplanner">
          <JQMHeader />
          <JQMPanel />
          <Content />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AppjQMPage2 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div data-role="page" id="afsprakenplanner">
          <JQMHeader />
          <JQMPanel />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MyMenu extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {

      };
    this.CloseClicked = this.CloseClicked.bind(this);
    this.HomelinkClicked = this.HomelinkClicked.bind(this);
    this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked = this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked.bind(this);
  }

  CloseClicked() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  }

  HomelinkClicked() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    this.props.parentCallback1();
  }

  AppjQMPage2linkClicked() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    this.props.parentCallback2();
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div id="mySidenav"  class="sidenav">
          <a href="#" class="closebtn" onClick={this.CloseClicked}>&times;</a>
            <a href='#' onClick={this.HomelinkClicked} >Home</a>
            <a href='#' onClick={this.AppjQMPage2linkClicked} >AppjQMPage2</a>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

class JQMHeader extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        };

    this.HamburgerClicked = this.HamburgerClicked.bind(this);
    }

    HamburgerClicked() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "440px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "440px";
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div data-role="header">
            <header>
                <div id="hamburger" onClick={this.HamburgerClicked}>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                <div id="h1"><h1>Afsprakenplanner</h1></div>
            </header>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class JQMPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    }

  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div data-role="panel" class="blackpanel" id="navpanel" data-display="push" data-theme="a" data-position="left">
          <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false">
              <h1>Maak account</h1>
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div id="panelhint">
                  Vul onderstaande gegevens in, en klik vervolgens op de knop Maak account.
              </div>
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Achternaam:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="naampan" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  E-mailadres:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="emailadrespan" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Wachtwoord:
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" id="password" /><span id="toggle" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye pass-icon" onclick="showhide();"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Telefoonnummer:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="telefoon" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Adres:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="adres" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Postcode:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="postcode" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div class="textcontainer">
                  Woonplaats:
              </div>
              <input type="text" id="woonplaats" />
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
              <div id="button"><input type="button" onclick="Controleer()" value="MAAK ACCOUNT" /></div>
              <div class="smallspacer"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
  


class Content extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div data-role="content" id='main'>
            <div id="contentLayer"></div>

            <div id="content">
                <h1>Afsprakenplanner</h1>
                <form id="theForm">
                    <div id="cont">
                        <div class="stack">
                            <div class="headertext">Naam en e-mailadres:</div>
                            <div id="inputsnaamemail">
                                <input type="text" id="naam" placeholder="Achternaam" data-mini="true" autocomplete="off" />
                                <ul id="namenlijst"></ul>
                                <input type="text" id="emailadres" placeholder="E-mailadres" data-mini="true" />
                            </div>
                            <div id="accfailure"><div id="accfailuretext">Geen account? </div><div id="maakaccbutton"><a data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="maak">Maak</a></div></div>
                        </div>
 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

style.css:

```
.stack {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px solid;
    min-width: 225px;
    max-width: 225px;
    height: 140px;
    color: royalblue;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
 }

header {
    height: 30px;
    top: 0;
}

#hamburger {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#content {
    padding: 22px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.largespacer {
    height: 120px;
}

div[data-role=panel][data-theme=a] {
    background: #3b5998;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.ui-shadow-inset, .ui-corner-all {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.blackpanel .ui-input-text {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: black;
}


#main {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mySidenav {
    overflow:visible;
    scrollbar-color: #3b5998 #3b5998;
}

#mySidenav::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 49px;
}

#mySidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background:#3b5998;
}

#mySidenav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #223868;
}

#mySidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #7ea0eb;
    color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: width .5s;
  }
  
  #mySidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
  }

  #mySidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
  }
```

hamburger.css:

```
header {
    background-color: #3b5998;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#h1 {
    font-size: 6px;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    position: fixed; /* or absolute */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}

/*
using background color is important to cover the menu
position absolute isset to cover the whole viewport
*/
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 52px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/*
the hamburger button with a little gradient effekt
*/
#hamburger {
    border: 1px solid #374C77;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    background: #4569b2;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #4569b2), color-stop(100%, #4062a5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4569b2 0%, #4062a5 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4569b2', endColorstr='#4062a5', GradientType=0);
}

    /*
The white stripes in the hamburger button
*/
    #hamburger div {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        height: 2px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        width: 90%;
    }

/*
The Layer that will be layed over the content
so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown
*/
#contentLayer {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            overflow: visible;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#maak").click(function () {
              $("#navpanel").panel('open');
            });
      });
    </script>
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React jQuery Mobile test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```